# Failed to load iwd_opc/payment/methods-renderers/cashondelivery template requested by "checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.cashondeliver

Tags: magento2.4, onepage-checkout, checkout-page, cash-on-delivery

Hello I am facing following error in IWD one page checkout.

**failed to load the "iwd_opc/payment/methods-renderers/cashondelivery" template requested by "checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.cashondeliver**

How can I check where is error?
in which template or js file have an error?

Thanks